# Android. Empty Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I copied database file from device and opened in SQLite client. Same query in the SQLite client returns results as expected but Android **sometimes** returns empty cursor. I can't explain why sometimes cursor returns 0 rows. SQLiteDatabase object is always opened per application because there is lots of requests to database per one task.

```
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
try {
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    try {
        Log.d("Cursor rows count size: ", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {                
                Long a= cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(TableA.a));
                String b = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TableA.b)));
                String c = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TableA.c));
                String d = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TableA.d));
                String e = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TableA.e));

                Object record = new Object (a, b, c, d, e);             
                list.add(record );              
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        } 
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }           
} finally {

}
```

**Updated**

SQL query (changed column and table names. There is no influence due to renaming):

```
SELECT
    a ,
    b ,
    c ,
    d ,
    e
FROM TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB ON(TableB._id=TableA.y_id)
    LEFT JOIN TableC ON(TableC._id=TableA.x_id)
WHERE active=1 AND xxx>1370090365365 AND xxx<1370867965365
ORDER BY TableA.xxx DESC
```

Like I said: this query runs as I expected and returns result in desktop SQLite client.

**Updated**

Besides I'm getting this kind warning despite all Cursor and SQLiteDatabase objects is wrapped by *try...finally* and closed.

```
W/CursorWrapperInner(10374): Cursor finalized without prior close()
```

Comment: Most interesting part is `query` variable, actually. Can you provide it's value?

Comment: Also, in the outer finally, close the database if you aren't going to use it

Answer (score 0):

I have never had to use the

```
cursor.close();
```

So that brings the question of how are you managing your cursor and that really depends on which what version you are targeting for your application.  For Honeycomb and later I would look at 'cursor loader', and prior to that 'startManagingCursor' was used, but I believe it recommend to user cursor loaders, this will eliminate the need for you to close the cursor.  Since the cursor is a async type task, you could be closing the cursor prior to it returning any results.

For cursor loaders I would suggest [How to use loaders in Android](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/)

You can also search for code at github.com or code.google.com, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Always use cursor.close, it wouldn't have a close method if you weren't meant to use it, close/end methods are like Java destructors, because you can't have destructors in java you have to use a method to specify when to get rid of connections etc, for example a sqlite database, when using the helpers you must close the SQLiteDatabase when you are done with it.

Comment: If you use a Cursor Loader, doesn't that manage it for you (and yes it calls the cursor close indirectly) and aren't you supposed to keep database activities out of the UI thread?

Comment: That would be the best thing to do yes, you should be using something like a AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing that this is inside a `SQLiteOpenHelper`, what I suggest, to avoid locks, is to use `getWritableDatabase` instead of `getReadableDatabase`, and instead of maintaining a database object for the duration of the activity/object/whatever is to have a few methods that handles all of it.

for example:

```
private SQLiteDatabase mWritable;

public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase(){
    if(mWritable == null)
        mWritable = this.getWritableDatabase();
    if(mWritable.isOpen())
        return mWritable;
    else
        mWritable = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return mWritable;
}

public void start(){
    mWritable = getDatabase();
}

public void stop(){
    if(mWritable != null)
        if(mWritable.isOpen())
            if(!mWritable.inTransaction())
                mWritable.close();
}

public void end(){
    if(mWritable == null)
        return;
    if(mWritable.isOpen()){
        if(mWritable.inTransaction())
            mWritable.endTransaction();
        mWritable.close();
    }
}
```

This can take care of managing the database. I also suggest adding some other methods to your helper as well, which may help out...

```
public Cursor Query(String query, String ... params){
    this.startReading();
    Cursor c = mWritable.rawQuery(query, params);
    return c;
}

public String GetScalar(String query, String ... params){
    String res = null;
    this.startReading();
    Cursor c;
    try {
        c = Query(query, params);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            if(!c.isNull(0)){
                res = c.getString(0);
            }
        }
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.stopReading();
    return res;
}

public String GetScalar(String query){
    return GetScalar(query, new String[0]);
}

public String[] GetColumn(String query, String ... params){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.startReading();
    Cursor c;
    try {
        c = Query(query, params);
        while(c.moveToNext()){
            if(!c.isNull(0)){
                list.add(c.getString(0));
            }
        }
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.stopReading();
    return list.toArray(new String[0]);
}

public String[] GetColumn(String query){
    return GetColumn(query, new String[0]);
}
```

I suggest that you copy the database from the device, either by using the application to copy the db, or if your application browsing to `data/data/<your package name>/databases/<database name>` and use SQLiteDatabaseBrowser (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) to go through it and run the query using this and check the results.

If you need to copy the database as you have no root access you can use something along the lines of:

```
public static boolean CopyDatabase(DbHelper dbHelper) {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//" + dbHelper.getPackageName()
                    + "//databases//" + DbHelper.DATABASE_NAME;
            String backupDBPath = "/Databases/";

            Log.d("Path", sd.getPath() + backupDBPath);
            File backupDir = new File(sd.getPath() + "/" + backupDBPath);
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);

            if (!backupDir.exists()) {
                if (!backupDir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d("Path", "Can not make directory");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("Path", "Directory exists");
            }

            File backupDB = new File(backupDir, DbHelper.DATABASE_NAME);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(currentDB);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(backupDB);
            FileChannel src = fis.getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = fos.getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
            return true;
        }
        Log.e("DbCopy", "Can not write to sdcard");
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```